# Using contactEvent method, what are attributes in linked DE used for?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

Reading the following resource about firing events:

https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/firing-events.md#Firing-an-Event-using-the-Fuel-REST-API-Events

I haven't quite been able to grasp the purpose of the attributes in the DE you create for the linked DE in a Contact Builder event. If all the attributes you'll need for your contact is already in the attribute group selected for the Event Destination, is there a real need to have any attributs in the event's linked DE?

Based on the example, does it imply that any contact key submitted for serialized event, need be an existing contact already in the root DE or all subscribers?

If a specific use case doesn't require use of attributes in a linked DE, then would the Events method be the recommended method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer your three questions, I'd like to explain that I published the page you refer to (which is an excerpt from [Journey Builder Developer's Guide](https://jbdevelopers.guide)) and it's helpful to read the other supporting chapters in the book to provide context.

That said, I'd like to start off by clarifying the differences of these two API methods to fire an Interaction.

The **ContactEvents** method is designed to support use cases where you have an existing Data Extension (Attribute Set) containing Contact data and you want to (a) capture a related Event for the Contact and (b) fire an Interaction, causing the Contact to enter an Interaction if they meet the defined Contact Filter Criteria. For example, a customer makes a purchase on an ecommerce website — the purchase is an Event. When this purchase occurs, the Event data is serialised into a Data Extension with transactional information related to the Contact and their purchase, for example: product SKU, purchase price and date. This causes the Contact to enter a post-purchase series Interaction.

The **Events** method is used when you want (a) Contact data to be serialized into the Data Source assigned to the Event (fomerly named 'Trigger') and (b) fire an Interaction, causing the Contact to enter an Interaction if they meet the defined Contact Filter Criteria.

Now onto answer your questions:

**Q:** If all the attributes you'll need for your contact is already in the attribute group selected for the Event Destination, is there a real need to have any attributes in the event's linked DE?

**A:** If you already have all the Attributes for the Contact Record and you simply want that Contact to enter an Interaction, then no, there's no real need to serialize any data at all. In this scenario, you could use the Events API to post and empty data object in your payload and still cause the Contact to enter the Interaction:

```
HOST: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /interaction-experimental/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer insert-accessToken-here

{
   "contactKey":"f2a075c6-3daf-4020-aff3-d0cf8ed65359",
   "eventDefinitionKey":"CONTACT-EVENT-eb0f4103-01f5-e729-8a27-465afcae3a1e",
   "data":{}
}
```

The magic name/value pair here is `contactKey`; this will cause the Contact to enter the Interaction.

**Q:** Based on the example, does it imply that any contact key submitted for serialized event, need be an existing contact already in the root DE or all subscribers?

**A:** In the case of the ContactEvents method, then yes, this is the assumption. However, if you don't have Contact Data then you can simply use the Events method to serialize the Contact Data into the Data Source.

**Q:** If a specific use case doesn't require use of attributes in a linked DE, then would the Events method be the recommended method?

**A:** As per my intial explanation, yes you would use the Events method in this scenario.

Comment: Super detailed, thanks for clarifying the nitty gritty details here. For the attributes sent in the linked DE using the contactEvents method, can we treat those attributes in the template as if they were subscriber attributes instead of using other functions like lookup()?

Comment: Yes and no. In the Nov 14 release, personalization string support was added for emails sent from Journey Builder, but the the data binding context used for personalization strings is the Event Source Data Extension, not the Contact model. I think you will need to use the `lookup()` AMPscript function.